# Having issues setting up cookies in Express and React app

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies

I am trying to set up cookies on my Express and React app, the Express server is hosted on port 8000 while the React app is hosted on port 3000. On the server side when I try sending the response to the client, I keep getting a `500: Internal Server Error`.

I think it's an issue with cors but I am not sure what.

My express server code

```
const express = require('express'),
      cors    = require('cors'),

const app = express()

// other requirements and stuff not pertaining to cookies

app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: process.env.LOGIN_SERVER_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false
    }
 }));

 const corsOptions = {
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     methods: "GET,HEAD,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS",
     credentials: true,
     allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
 }

 app.options("*", cors(corsOptions))

 app.get("/api/cookie", cors(corsOptions),  (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: false,
        domain: "http://localhost:3000" 
    }

    return res
        .cookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", options)
        .status(200)
        .send("cookie sent")
 })
```

I am trying to fetch the cookie within my App.js file in the componentDidMount() lifecycle method, then console.logging the response but the response is just the `500: Internal Server Error` I was talking about. I have a proxy set up between the two also.

Here is my React App component

```
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {}

    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch('/api/cookie', {credentials:'include'})
             .then(response => {console.log(response)})
             .catch(err => {console.log(error)})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // routes to pages
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no port in the `fetch()` URL so that's going to go to the same port and host as your web page, but it sounds like your api server might be on a different port (8000 vs 3000).

Comment: I have a proxy set up so I dont need to specify the port within the fetch call

Comment: So, you have a proxy that is directing the `/api/cookie` to the right port?  The 500 status sounds like it may coming from the proxy.  Unless that status is somehow coming out of the cors middleware, it's not coming from any of the other code you show here so there's either more code you haven't shown us causing it or the error is from the proxy.  If you put a do-nothing except log and call `next()` middleware as the first middleware in this server, does it even get called when you issue the `fetch()`?  If not, the problem is elsewhere before the request gets to this server.

Comment: Correct. I dont think its an issue with the proxy because I have other fetch calls that work just fine. I think its the cors middleware because I am getting nothing on the server side so I think it doesnt get passed the middleware

Comment: My suggesetion is to put `app.use((req,res, next) => { console.log(`got here ${req.url}`); next()})` as the very first middleware and see if it logs anything.  If it does, then set a breakpoint and step into the cors middleware and see what it's doing.  If it does not, then the problem is elsewhere, not in this server code.

Comment: For some reason the only thing that gets logged to the console is got here /scripts/scripts.js

Comment: Well, something upstream of your server is apparently blocking your `fetch()` call or sending it to the wrong place.  That seems like either a client-side problem or a proxy problem.

Comment: could it have anything to do with my fetch method? Because all of my other fetch calls are working fine

Comment: Are all your other `fetch()` calls going to the same server you're showing here?  I don't see anything obviously wrong with the `fetch()` code.  It doesn't appear to be a CORS issue because it isn't even getting to your server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210278/discussion-between-noahdubs-and-jfriend00).